# Continuing to put data on Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Is there anyway to continuously load data on one list view? I tried doing this but the second setadapter overrides the first one. Here is my code:

```
ArrayAdapter<Display> adapter = new DisplayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.display_list_item, response.container.InactiveDisplay);
existingItemsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

ArrayAdapter<Display> adapter1 = new DisplayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.display_list_item, response.container.ActiveDisplay);
existingItemsListView.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution:

```
    List<MyAdapterItems> myItems = 
    ((MyAdapter)myListView.getAdapter()).getMyAdapterItems;
  /*
   *You can use myitems.add(Object o) method to add items then you can call
    */
    myListView.setAdapter(myItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

add data to first adapters array and then call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();` to notify listview that there is new data to load